# sum values in datagridview with out using for each row vb.net

Tags: vb.net

my question is how to sum cell values  in datagridview using faster than my code

col1....col2.....col3

1 ........3.........22

2 ....... 4.........22

4 ........1 ........55

10........1 ........22

this is my code

```
barcount = 0
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If row.Cells(3).Value = 22  Then
        barcount += (row.Cells(1).Value * row.Cells(2).Value)
    End If
Next
```

or

how to use

barcount = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Select CStr(row.Cells(0).Value*row.Cells(1).Value) where row.Cells(3).Value=3

thanks

Comment: Where you getting this data, if from DB then do it there. Anything dealing with data is slower always after retrieving it. If you spit it out the way you need it, then theres no manipulation after... Also use the columns name **never** use the column index, what happens if you want to rearrange columns, your logic is now broke.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You say that you want something faster than using a loop but LINQ will not be faster.  LINQ allows you to write more succinct code but it will rarely be faster and usually be slower than a well-written alternative.

That said, the LINQ to replace that loop would look like this:

```
Dim barCount = DataGridView1.Rows.
                             Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().
                             Where(Function(row) CInt(row.Cells(3).Value) = 22).
                             Sum(Function(row) CInt(row.Cells(1).Value) * CInt(row.Cells(2).Value))
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, YOU SAID THAT USUALLY BE SLOWER, you mean for huge data in gridview will be slower than loop

Comment: LINQ code is almost always slower than an equivalent loop and will generally only be faster if it can simplify and otherwise complex, multi-step query.  In most cases though, the difference is going to be negligible because of the nature of the query and the amount of data involved.  I mentioned it because you said that you wanted something faster but you generally use LINQ for simplicity, not performance.  If in doubt, just time both options to see the difference.

Comment: A good way to determine if linq is slower or faster than a loop is to inspect the compiled JIT code of both variants